# Mysql only do not select duplicated values

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to run a simple `SELECT` statment. I have a table which has two columns: `id` and `email`.

I want to run a `SELECT` statment that won't return duplicate values. For example, take the following data:

```
1   example@hotmail.com
2   example12@hotmail.com
3   example@hotmail.com
4   example@hotmail.com
```

I want it to return only the following:

```
1   example@hotmail.com
2   example12@hotmail.com
```

...and skip the duplicate values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(id), email FROM some_table GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 11):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table
```

Answer (score 6):

If you `don't need ID` use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM `TABLE_NAME`
```

else If you need the `First ID` use

```sql
SELECT MIN(ID),email FROM `TABLE_NAME` GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, one is to use the DISTINCT clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM your_table;
```

another way is to summarize counts of the values:

```sql
SELECT COUNT (*), email from your_table GROUP BY email;
```

Comment: You first solution will return every row, as will your second solution.

Comment: Yeah, guess he did say he just wants the email value... edited my answer to reflect only the email column.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUE_FEILD_NAME FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```